# NovaExchange API: Converting Python Code to NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js

i am writing an API for NODEJS but the example provided on the novaexchange site is written in Python thus making it difficult for me to write the equivalent in NodeJS. Help would be much appreciated. Code Written Down in Python
[https://www.novaexchange.com/remote/faq/](http://NovaExchange%20API)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import requests

# https://novaexchange.com/remote/faq/

API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"
API_SECRET = "YOUR_API_SECRET"

public_set = set([ "markets", "market/info", "market/orderhistory", "market/openorders" ]) # optional
private_set = set([ "getbalances", "getbalance", "getdeposits", "getwithdrawals", "getnewdepositaddress", "getdepositaddress", "myopenorders", "myopenorders_market", "cancelorder", "withdraw", "trade", "tradehistory", "getdeposithistory", "getwithdrawalhistory", "walletstatus" ])

url = "https://novaexchange.com/remote/v2/"

def api_query( method, req = None ):
        url = "https://novaexchange.com/remote/v2/"
        if not req:
                req = {}
        if method.split('/')[0][0:6] == 'market':
                r = requests.get( url + method + '/', timeout = 60 )
        elif method.split('/')[0] in private_set:
                url += 'private/' + method + '/' + '?nonce=' + str( int( time.time() ) )
                req["apikey"] = API_KEY
                req["signature"] = base64.b64encode( hmac.new( API_SECRET, msg = url, digestmod = hashlib.sha512 ).digest() )
                headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                r = requests.post( url, data = req, headers = headers, timeout = 60 )
        return r.text

# Eample usage:

# Public:
# print api_query( "markets" )
print api_query( "market/orderhistory/" + "LTC_DOGE" )
# etc...

# Private:
print api_query("getbalances")
# print api_query( "trade/" + "LTC_DOGE", { 'tradebase': 0, 'tradetype': "BUY", 'tradeprice': 0.000001, 'tradeamount': 1000 } )
# print api_query( 'cancelorder/' + str( 1426936 ) )
# print api_query( 'tradehistory' )
# etc...
```